# Name of right below corner control?

Tags: wpf

What is this control name in WPF?

Name of right below corner control?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a control, it is a property of the `Window` that causes it to be re-sizable with a "grip".

Set the `ResizeMode` to `CanResizeWithGrip` and you will see the grip in the bottom-right corner.

```
<Window ...
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
>
</Window>
```

Comment: Actually, it is a control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.resizegrip(v=vs.110).aspx but you usually only need to use it directly when you're designing custom window chrome.